# C++ pointer to class in a kind

Tags: c++, class

This is a snippet of an open source code. Full source code is available https://github.com/gec/dnp3/blob/master/src/opendnp3/DNP3/ResponseContext.h

```
ObjectWriteIterator owi = arAPDU.WriteContiguous(apObject, start,stop);

  for(size_t i = start; i <= stop; ++i) {       
    if(owi.IsEnd()) { // out of  space in the fragment          
       this->mStaticWriteMap[arKey] =
              boost::bind(&ResponseContext::WriteStaticObjects<T>, this, apObject,
         arStart, arStop, arKey, _1);                       return false;       
     }

    apObject->Write(*owi, arStart->mValue);         
    ++arStart; //increment the iterators
    ++owi;     
   }
```

---

```
ObjectWriteIterator::ObjectWriteIterator() :  
  mpPos(NULL),  
  mIndex(1), 
  mStart(0),   
  mStop(0),  
  mObjectSize(0)   
{}
```

My question is: I don't understand is where `*owi` is referring in this context.

Answer (score 0):

`owi` is an [`iterator`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/), which is a 'standard' C++ interface for *iterating* over some collection.

The interface has them use pointer-symantics, so the `*` operator 'dereferences' the iterator and returns a reference to the value it currently 'points' to, and incrementing it via `++` moves it to the next item in the collection being iterated over.

In this case, it looks like a collection of `ObjectWrite` objects inside the collection specified by `apObject` between `start` and `stop` (start and stop are also typically defined by `iterators` set to some location in the collection).

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I was earlier not sure about one can build a self contained 'Mock up' iterator class which use hidden is the header file

> inline boost::uint8_t* ObjectWriteIterator::operator*() const 
>   {
>     if(this->IsEnd()) throw InvalidStateException(LOCATION, "End of
>   iteration");
>   return mpPos; 
>   }

in the header file. Sorry for wild goose run. Thanks for the prompt reply and I learned something new about the the core implementation of the iterator as well.